# ASP.NET Core MVC dynamic return is not camelCased

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, camelcasing

Return a strongly typed object from your service, and it renders JSON properties as camelCase, because that's the default in ASP.NET Core MVC.

However, sometimes we need to create something on the fly using `dynamic` keyword and `ExpandoObject` class.

Those properties are not camelCased any more.

Howe to force ASP.NET Core MVC To cameCase everything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within your Startup.cs you can specify a resolver to use for serialisation. The one you are looking for is CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver and it can be enabled with the following:

```
        services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        });
```

I have tested it with a dynamic type and it is working as expected.

Comment: I've tried this using ASP.NET Core 2.2, but to no revail, I still see dynamic objects within a typed object being (Upper)PascalCase instead of camelCase, while the typed object properties are indeed camelCase...

Answer (score 4):

On .NET 5 there is a specific flag to configure to serialize the dictionary keys

```
services.AddControllers()
                .AddJsonOptions(o =>
                    o.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = System.Text.Json.JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
                );
```

More info
[JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.dictionarykeypolicy?view=net-5.0)
[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/47707#issuecomment-779372893)

Answer (score 1):

I've recently been trying to serialise an `ExpandoObject` into `camelCase` using `System.Text.Json` without much luck. However, I did manage to achieve this using `Newtonsoft.Json`.

For those who might be looking for a unit-level or non-MVC solution as opposed to the configuration-level solution suggested above like myself, here are my findings.

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
d.Foo = new ExpandoObject();
d.Foo.BarBaz = null;
```

Using `System.Text.Json` with `JsonSerializerOptions`, the property names are serialised, however, the value given to `PropertyNamingPolicy` for `camelCase` seems to be ignored during serialisation at present (tested on `.NET 5`, at time of writing). It does, however, continue to serialise the object without failure or exception.

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
};

string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<ExpandoObject>(d, options);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

This would output

> {"Foo":{"BarBaz":null}}

I was able to achieve the desired effect using the [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm) suggested previously as the instance of [`ContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/JSON/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_ContractResolver.htm) to use for the [`JsonSerialierSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/JSON/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) instance passed into the `SerializeObject` method.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{ 
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() 
};

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d, settings);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

The output being...

> {"foo":{"barBaz":null}}